# Expand dates at summer months

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe.

```
id  start         end      var
1   03JAN2009   15FEB2009   2
1   16FEB2009   05MAY2009   3
1   06MAY2009   07MAY2009   4
1   07MAY2009   03JUN2009   5
1   04JUN2009   12DEC2009   6
2   04FEB2009   02FEB2010   8
```

I need to expand the start and end dates at breakpoints-May 1st, Jun 1st, Oct 1st, Nov 1st and Dec 1st for all ids.
The final output must be

```
    id  start         end      var
    1   03JAN2009   15FEB2009   2
    1   16FEB2009   30APRY2009  3
    1   01MAY2009   05MAY2010   3
    1   06MAY2009   07MAY2009   4
    1   07MAY2009   31MAY2009   5
    1   01JUN2009   03JUN2009   5
    1   04JUN2010   01SEPT2009  6
    1   01OCT2009   31OCT2010   6
    1   01NOV2010   30NOV2009   6
    1   01DEC2009   12DEC2010   6
    2   04FEB2009   30APR2009   8
    2   01MAY2009   31MAY2009   8
    2   01JUN2009   30SEPT2009  8
    2   01OCT2009   31OCT2009   8
    2   01NOV2009   31NOV2009   8
   2    01DEC2009   02FEB2010   8
```

I am looking for a solution in data.table or dplyr though data.table solution is preferable.

Comment: I'd probably start with using "proper" date or timestamps, not strings like this. After that, I'd probably extract the month (as a number) and then use `cut`. (And then some more logic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be mistaken, but this seems as easy as adding all the dates you need then sorting.

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "id  start         end      var
1   03JAN2009   15FEB2009   2
1   16FEB2009   05MAY2009   3
1   06MAY2009   07MAY2009   4
1   07MAY2009   03JUN2009   5
1   04JUN2009   12DEC2009   6
2   04FEB2009   02FEB2010   8")

fmt <- '%d%b%Y'
add <- c('May', 'Jun', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
add <- as.Date(sprintf('01%s2009', add), fmt)

dat <- within(dat, {
  start <- as.Date(start, fmt)
  end <- as.Date(end, fmt)
})

## add the extra dates, merge back to original, fill in missing values
pad <- function(data, add) {
  dates <- sort(c(data$start, data$end, add, add - 1))
  dates <- data.frame(
    matrix(dates, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c('start', 'end')))
  )
  dates[] <- lapply(dates, as.Date, origin = '1970-01-01')
  
  res <- merge(dates, data, by = 'start', all = TRUE)
  setNames(
    data.frame(na.omit(res$id)[1], res[1:2], zoo::na.locf(res$var, na.rm = FALSE)),
    names(data)
  )
}
```

test to make sure the function works for one id

```
pad(dat[dat$id == 2, ], add)
#   id      start        end var
# 1  2 2009-02-04 2009-04-30   8
# 2  2 2009-05-01 2009-05-31   8
# 3  2 2009-06-01 2009-09-30   8
# 4  2 2009-10-01 2009-10-31   8
# 5  2 2009-11-01 2009-11-30   8
# 6  2 2009-12-01 2010-02-02   8
```

Apply to the rest of the data

```
sp <- split(dat, dat$id)
res <- do.call('rbind', lapply(sp, pad, add = add))
rownames(res) <- NULL
within(res, {
  start <- format(start, fmt)
  end <- format(end, fmt)
})
#    id     start       end var
# 1   1 03Jan2009 15Feb2009   2
# 2   1 16Feb2009 30Apr2009   3
# 3   1 01May2009 05May2009   3
# 4   1 06May2009 07May2009   4
# 5   1 07May2009 31May2009   5
# 6   1 01Jun2009 03Jun2009   5
# 7   1 04Jun2009 30Sep2009   6
# 8   1 01Oct2009 31Oct2009   6
# 9   1 01Nov2009 30Nov2009   6
# 10  1 01Dec2009 12Dec2009   6
# 11  2 04Feb2009 30Apr2009   8
# 12  2 01May2009 31May2009   8
# 13  2 01Jun2009 30Sep2009   8
# 14  2 01Oct2009 31Oct2009   8
# 15  2 01Nov2009 30Nov2009   8
# 16  2 01Dec2009 02Feb2010   8
```

I don't know anything about dplyr, so I leave that exercise to you

Comment: Thanks so much rawr!  I also have 10 years of data-2007-2017.  For some IDs, there could be data spanning across two years.  For example I could have ID=3, start= 04JUN2010   end=12DEC2012   var=6.  How would the code change in the case?  I am new to R and I am not able to get the required result.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: just supply the function with all the dates you need: `add <- c(add, add + 365, add + 365 * 2, add + 365 * 3)` then run it as usual

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!